# Generate an email alert to the Issue Owner

Tags: apex, email

I have created a custom object(1) in my organization with a check box and a look up field link to the main object(1).

I need to create a task when a user, other than the Owner of object(1), creates/inserts a new record. The task needs to generate an email alert to the `Issue Owner` of the main object(1).

Only display records if check-box is ticked. there is a description field in object(1) that should be the subject of email

Note: object(2) is the related list of object(1).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this two ways, one all in a trigger

```
Trigger Object2After(After insert){

List<Id> parentIds = new List<Id>{};

List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();  

For(Object2__c obj : trigger.new)
ParentIds.add(obj.Object1__c);

Map<Id, Object1__c> idObj1Map = new Map<Id, Object1__c>([select Id, Name, OwnerId from Object1__c where Id IN :parentIds]);

For(Object2__c obj2 : trigger.new){
Id parentOwnerId = idObj1Map.get(obj2.Object1__c).OwnerId;

if(obj2.OwnerId != parentOwnerId ){ //diff owner

   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();  
   string body = 'Hi ';    
       mail.setSubject(obj2.Name + ' is the related list of ' + obj1.Name );  
       mail.setTargetObjectId(parentOwnerId);  
       mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  
       mail.setHtmlBody(body);  
       mails.add(mail);  
    }
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);  
    }
```

Alternatively you could stamp the parent record owner Id on the related record via a before trigger and then use a workflow email alert to actually send out the email.

Comment: I think workflow should be good option than having in a trigger since that will give extra edge of switching off and on the mails sent.

Comment: thank You Mohith, Its my mistake I haven’t asked you the correct question. If the check box is ticked then the record should display in Object(1) are else it shouldn’t but in both cases email should generate to user, and if the record is created by owner itself then email should not generate . In this case email subject should be in object(1)subjectField/object(2)subjectField  ex:- test1/test2 and email body of object(2)someCommentField

Comment: You cannot choose to selectively display ir not display records in a related list. What you can do is include the checkbox column on the related list and sort by it, so that the checked records appear at the top. You can adjust the subject as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have a lookup relationship we can think of after insert and after update trigger that checks that owner of parent and child is different and also we can check if the flag field is true send the Outbound Email message .You may like to bulkify the trigger while sending outbound email messages due to governor limits .

Comment: I havent done this type of task before is there any sample code for this